# SQL Table commands to show certain data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, openafs

I have IT homework that is due at midnight tonight. For our assignment, we had to create a table in an SQL database off my school AFS database. I am using MobaXTerm to do this homework assignment.

I created a table name "student". I created the entire table correctly. It is correct, because my professor gave me the exact command to create it. Here are the columns in order: id, firstname, lastname, address, state, gpa, credits. I populated this table with 20 students, however I do not want to post the picture of the result on here, because it has personal info on it.

I answered the other questions correctly, however I am stuck on this question that has multiple questions in it:

5. Next, write and run (issue) SQL queries that do the following. For each query, provide screenshots for the SQL query and the results within a Word document so I can grade it.

a.  Show state and gpa information about students with the first name Peter (I was told to add students with the name "Peter" before I created this table).
This one is correct here is the command i used:
`select state, gpa, firstname from student where lastname = 'Peter';`

b. Retrieve the last names, state, and credits of all students that are NOT from AZ or FL. Order by the state.

I am struggling on this one, because I do not know how to show the table of students that are both NOT from AZ and FL.

But here is a command that worked to show if they are not from one state.
`select, lastname, credits, state from student where state != 'AZ'`

How am I supposed to write that student is not equal to both AZ and FL?

c.  How many students live on '10 Main Street'?

`select id, address from student where address='10 Main Street';`

This question is correct.

d. Retrieve all sophomore student ids along with their credits that are NOT C students (see the table for definition for “sophomore” and “C” grades).

So the table shows that a sophomore has 33-64 credits. A C student has a GPA of 1.7-2.69. So what is my line of command to show these range of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Q: How am I supposed to write that student is not equal to both AZ and FL?

```
... WHERE state != 'AZ' AND state != 'FL'
```

Q: How many students ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_students FROM ...
```

Q: Sophmore not C

```
... WHERE credits >= 33 AND credits <= 64
      AND NOT ( gpa >= 1.7 AND gpa <= 2.69)
```

Comment: As i written above, I already said that the How many students question is correct.

Comment: It's not. @spencer7593 is.

Comment: @spencer7593 actually the answer i had there was right. the results came out correct. It shows all students that live on Main Street. The id part was just to number the students so i can count them.

Comment: And also here is another question i am struggling on: e. Determine if there are any students from CT with at least a ‘C’ or if there are any AZ students that have a ‘seniors’. Show their lastname and State. Order the information by state.

Comment: @potanta:  I recommend you review some basic elements of SQL comparison operators...  **`>`**, **`>=`**, **`=`** (and how those operate on a variety of datatypes), and logical operators **`NOT`**, **`AND`**, **`OR`**, and using parentheses to specify the sequence of operations (over the normal order of precedence). If I want write a query that answers the question "how many", I am very apt to use an aggregate function e.g. `SUM(1)`, `COUNT(DISTINCT id)`, etc. You may consider a list of id values as an "already correct" answer to "how many". But I don't.